# Copy pictures from Content Controls to different Content Control

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a process that allows users to open Doc1 and populate the content controls of Doc2. This works fine for plain text but I'm running into a wall regarding both rich text and more importantly, pictures that are inside of Rich Text Content Controls.

Unsurprisingly the following does not set anything but text:

```
ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("ct2").Item(1).Range.Text = ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("ct1").Item(1).Range.Text
```

I also have tried:

```
ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("ct1").Item(1).Range.Copy
ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("ct2").Item(1).Range.Paste
```

While this appears to work it's not just copying the text and picture(s) but the content control as well. So I end up with ct1 inside of ct2.

Comment: I can't look too much into it, but obviously pictures aren't going to be stored the same way as text. I don't know if ms-word stores them in shapes like excel but that would be your best bet to start looking at the MSDN documentation regarding that. Then you may end up having to use a 'copy paste' type method to copy it, or save it to a temporary file from doc 1 and insert it into doc2 using the temp file path (preferred, because you're not relying on the clipboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work with a simple test. Essentially, select your copy location and delete it in place. This will keep your cursor exactly where you left off. Then paste it in. This code assumes that the picture you're replacing is after the initial picture. I.E. The picture you copy is earlier in the document than your `copy to` location.

```
Public Sub MoveCCPic()

    ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("ct1").Item(1).Range.Copy
    ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("ct2").Item(1).Range.Select

    ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("ct2").Item(1).Delete
    Selection.Paste

    ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("ct1").Item(2).Title = "ct2"

End Sub
```

You may run into some additional code around if there is not any text between your picture boxes.

Comment: Certainly not the elegance I was looking for but this solves my dilemma nonetheless, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to `Word VBA` where hack-arounds are the answer! ;-) Nice username.